# Is it possible to have more "roundy" texture on terrain in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, terrain

I am using the smallest brush size, so it paints in a square.

Is it possible to have a small round brush?

For example in this image the 45° road is not so realistic. How could I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you'll have to just increase the *Control Texture Resolution*. That, or create a custom projector shader, which seems like overkill.

Relevant link: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/terrain-OtherSettings.html

Comment: Thanks, it works. But it removes all previous textures. Can I save it somehow?

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry.

Comment: And what size do you think is optimal? I want bigger and bigger resolution, but I don't want to make my game use a lot of resources. Is 2048 big?

Comment: Any decent computer should be able to handle 2048.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Have a nice day :)